# Breeze Typescript Tooling

Tags: typescript, breeze

Using the fantastic [Breeze Typescript Entity Generator tool](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.tooling/tree/master/TypeScriptEntityGen) but keep getting error

```
Error: Unable to locate the default implementation of the 'modelLibrary' interface. Possible options are 'ko', 'backingStore' or 'backbone'. See the breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances method.
```

The error is happening at this line in tsgen-core.js:

```
var metadataStore = breeze.MetadataStore.importMetadata(metadata);
```

I am sure it is grabbing the metadata fine. It seems like I should be configuring breeze with an interfaceAdapter, but the example in the repo doesn't configure anything on breeze before using it to importMetadata for this tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We forgot to update `tsgen.js` for the latest version of breeze-client, which uses `breeze.base.debug.js` as the default js file instead of breeze.debug.js.  The breeze.debug.js file has a default modelLibrary, but breeze.base.debug.js does not.

I've updated [tsgen.js](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.tooling/tree/master/TypeScriptEntityGen) to use breeze.debug.js.  Please get the latest and try again.

Comment: I updated my tsgen to use 

var breeze = require('breeze-client/breeze.debug');

but I get error : Cannot find module 'breeze-client/breeze.debug'

in package.json I have

"breeze-client": "2.0.0-alpha.18",

how can I get this debug file?

Comment: I recommend that you use new newer [breeze-metadata-generator](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.tooling/tree/master/breeze-entity-generator) which is available as an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/breeze-entity-generator)

Comment: I have some custom stuff built out so I did look through the current code and saw I could do this. fixed by doing this instead

var backing = require('breeze-client/bundles/breeze-client-adapter-model-library-backing-store.umd');
 var breeze = require('breeze-client/bundles/breeze-client.umd');

and then calling
 backing.ModelLibraryBackingStoreAdapter.register()

in my generate method;

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on going from IEdmModel to metadata.json and ran into this.  To address your issue I had to register the model library backing:

```
var backing = require('breeze-client/bundles/breeze-client-adapter-model-library-backing-store.umd');
var breeze = require('breeze-client/bundles/breeze-client.umd');

backing.ModelLibraryBackingStoreAdapter.register();
```

To get the metadata csdl, I put together an extension method to convert IEdmModel to csdl.

https://gist.github.com/Rodbourn/691e5277f061b26189820c03504a544b